# Selenium disable popup 'Restore page'- VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-chromedriver, restore

I am using selenium ChromeDriver in **VBA**.

1. None of the `bot.AddArgument` seem to disable the popup “Restore Pages? Chrome didn't shut down correctly.”
   [restore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bLHV.jpg)
2. I want the page to open with the URL and not first open Google search page.I want to do this programmatically (not manually add a new 'On startup' in the browser settings).

   ```
   Sub VBAChromeDriverBot()
   Dim b As Boolean
   Dim URL  As String
   Dim bot As New ChromeDriver
   bot.SetProfile "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\ChromeProfile2"
   bot.AddArgument "url=https://stackoverflow.com/"
   bot.AddArgument "--disable-extensions"
   bot.AddArgument "--disable-session-crashed-bubble"
   bot.AddArgument "--disable-application-cache"
   bot.AddArgument "--disable-popup-blocking"
   bot.AddArgument "--disable-notifications"
   bot.AddArgument "--test-type"

   URL = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
   bot.Get URL
   If b = False Then bot.Window.Maximize: b = True
   Stop
   bot.Quit
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: This might be a programmatic approach though is altering preferences file. Should be easy enough to write a vba version as python is pretty readable as to what it is doing _https://dev.to/cuongld2/get-rid-of-chrome-restore-bubble-popup-when-automate-gui-test-using-selenium-3pmh_

Comment: Thanks @QHarr! I Implemented your suggestion in VBA and it works :)

Comment: you are most welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing QHarr suggestion in VBA:

```
Sub VBAChromeDriverBot()
Dim b As Boolean
Dim URL  As String
Dim bot As New ChromeDriver
bot.SetProfile "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\ChromeProfile2"
Call ReplaceStringInFile
URL = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
bot.Get URL
If b = False Then bot.Window.Maximize: b = True
Stop
bot.Quit
End Sub

Sub ReplaceStringInFile()
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Dim objFSO
Dim objTS 'define a TextStream object
Dim strContents As String
Dim folderpath As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim FileNamefound As String

folderpath = Environ$("USERPROFILE") &"\Documents\ChromeProfile2\Default\"
FileName = "Preferences"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile(folderpath & FileName, ForReading)
strContents = objTS.ReadAll
strContents = Replace(strContents, "Crashed", "none")
objTS.Close
Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile(folderpath & FileName, ForWriting)
objTS.Write strContents
objTS.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Nicely implemented though cleaner to explicitly type all your variables and you don't need the CALL keyword.